# Media library and Upload media problem

Tags: plugins, uploads, media

I have a client who is running the metro pro theme on genesis and for a week now the client has not been able to add media in blog posts. I have done all the usual like deactivate all plugins, uploaded a fresh install of WordPress and still the problems persist. I deleted all the W3TC caching folders and backed up the website just.

I checked the media library and that is blank even though in wp-content/uploads all of the images are there. I am able to upload images from media > add-new but again they are not showing up in the media library and I am able to view the image from it's public permalink.

I am not too sure what else I can try. I had W3TC setup with maxCDN and have deleted all of those already but still the problem persists .Everything is up t date including the Genesis framework and child theme. I know my client gave access to a friend of hers who done some other work to the site but what I do not know.

Does anyone here have any clues as I turned on the wp-debug and nothing is showing up their either.
Many thanks

Phillip Dews

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console or the server logs you can share with us?

Comment: Hi Andrew all the consol shows is that JQMigrate is installed and there are no error logs on the site. I am thinking it's a theme issue so I am making a carbon copy of the site on a subdomain as we speak fella.

Comment: Activating _TwentySeventeen_ is another quick way to test if the issue is theme related.